# How to read .wav files one after the other?

Tags: matlab, wav

I used wavread() to read in 3 wave files:

```
[wave_1 f1]=wavread(s1);
[wave_2 f2]=wavread(s2);
[wave_3 f3]=wavread(s3);
```

where s1,s2,s3 are the paths for the wave files. The problem is that they are played all at once. How can I play the first, then the second, then the third one after the another?

Comment: `wavread` doesn't play the file...

Answer (score 0):

To play the files sequentially, use the [`playblocking`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audioplayer.playblocking.html) function. Here is what your code would look like:

```
[wave_1 f1] = wavread(s1);
[wave_2 f2] = wavread(s2);
[wave_3 f3] = wavread(s3);

player1 = audioplayer(wave_1, f1);
playblocking(player1);

player2 = audioplayer(wave_2, f2);
playblocking(player2);

player3 = audioplayer(wave_3, f3);
playblocking(player3);
```